# Running Fedora20 on a sata drive connected to a usb

Tags: fedora

I want to install Fedora20 on a SATA drive connected via a USB cable.  Eventually, it will be connected to the motherboard of the PC but until then only on the USB.  I don't want to use the cutdown version of LiveCD on usb with persistent data for this reason.

The existing PC has windows installed, I want the disk to be loaded according to the precedence set in the BIOS without any modifications to the MBR on the windows disk.  So basically, I want to be able to remove the sata disk at any time and have the computer boot into windows as it does now, not GRUB menu etc.

Is this possible? If so, how might I achieve this?

There may be a better solution to this that I don't know about.  For example, some way of starting a virtual machine with some sort of VirtualBox Boot CD or something.  If there is a better solution I would like to know about it also but the major requirement is that I can't affect the existing windows disk.

Comment: This should be entirely possible as you've laid it out.

Comment: @slm I edited the question and added `If so, how might I achieve this?`

Comment: Install as normal.  The only think I could add is first physically disconnect your Windows HDD if you can, to save embarrassment if you were to accidentally install onto the wrong drive.  Everything else should "just work".

Comment: @garethTheRed it worked, even with the original windows disk connected.  I have had problems with this is the past but thinking back it was only because I was installing on a partition on the same disk so it had to overwrite the MBR. cheers.